# AS3 sockets and policy file request to a C# server

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, flash, sockets, policy

This problem is driving me crazy! I've read *all* the questions on Stack Overflow but I'm still stuck.

My as3 program works very well, but when I have finished it and put it on a server, it starts to request this famous policy file.

AS3 script:

```
socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onClose);
socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
socket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecError);
socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onResponse);

socket.connect( MYHOST, 4242 );
```

C# server code:

```
TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(4242);
TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
serverSocket.Start();
clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
StreamReader read = new StreamReader(networkStream, Encoding.UTF8);
StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(networkStream, Encoding.UTF8);

response = read.ReadLine();

if (response.Contains("policy"))
{
 write.Write("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"*\" /></cross-domain-policy>\0");
 write.Flush();
 clientSocket.Close();
 return;
}
```

So, when the AS3 doesn't find the policy on the default port 843 (or something similar), it asks directly on the same socket as the connection.
My C# code sees the request and replies, after which the AS3 script closes the connection (which is OK), but it never reconnects.

I have tried to put this in the AS3 **before** the connect():

```
Security.loadPolicyFile( "xmlsocket://myhost.com:4242");
```

But when I do the `connect()` it simply gets stuck and never requests the policy file. After I close the AS3 application, my server sees the request, but the connection is closed. It's like the client forget to do a flush.

Can someone tell me how I can solve this problem correctly?

Comment: Do you try to turn on the flash player policy log, I think it may help to clarify what is going on. To turn policy log on you need the debug version of flash [player](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) and [mm.cfg](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fc9.html) file in your home directory with flag _PolicyFileLog_ set to 1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i have a problem.
I dont know wich package i must download!!
I have windows 7 and there arent downloads for it!

Comment: Windows Flash Player 11.7 ActiveX control content debugger (for IE)
Windows Flash Player 11.7 Plugin content debugger (for Netscape-compatible browsers - FireFox and Chrome (but for Chrome you have to disable native paper plugin)
Windows Flash Player 11.7 Projector content debugger (for debug without browser)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After 3 days i have finally discovered what is the bug in the code.

A bounty of 50 points and no one have noticed it :-(

Is very stupid, a novice error:

When the flash application ask for the policy file dont send the newline char, but the terminating char '\0'.

and im reading with the read.ReadLine(); that read until the '\n', so it stuck.

Thank you all for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a problem similar to your's. The fact is, that while running a Flash app into a C#, it lose lot's of requests which port differs from standart. The solution is not to use such requests in Flash. So you have to put them into C#, and call this functions with Flash's ExternalInterface.call. When the request is completed, your C# must call a Flash function, passing req's answer as a parameter.

Comment: What do you mean by "running a Flash app into a C#"? The topic starter has a C# server rather than C# client and as3 client.